# Is it possible to make nodes in graph blinking using pyvis?

Tags: python, html, pyvis

I want my nodes in graph to change their colour dynamically

I tried to use color parameter like this
G.add_node(node, color = ['red', 'white'])
It doesn't work.

I am ready to change result html, but I don't know how to find exact node by its name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.